# How to pass Array of Images from a tableView to another DetailView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class ListView:
UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate  {

    var data = ["Settings ", "Power", "Background Image",
      "My favorates","My collections","Music", "Videos", "Photos"]
    var detailImages : Array<UIImage> = [
     UIImage(named: "r1.png")!, 
     UIImage(named: "r2.png")!,
     UIImage(named: "r4.png")!,
     UIImage(named: "r5.png")!,
     UIImage(named: "r6.png")!]

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",
          forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        //cell.textLabel?.text = "Next View"

        // to show the alternate color in cells

        if  indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else

        {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
      didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InterestViewController")
          as! InterestViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextView, 
          animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Note that for a small number of images you can load the images into an array in memory, but that approach does not scale well. If you have 10+ images and they are at all large you run the risk of running out of memory. In general it's a better idea to use an array of image paths/URLs from the local file system, and load the images into memory as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare property

```
var detailImages = [UIImage]()
```

in `InterestViewController`, and assign your images to this property in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let nextView = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InterestViewController") as? InterestViewController else {return}
    nextView.detailImages = detailImages
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextView, animated: true)
}
```